# How to create ZipArchive correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5, zip

i'm writing Desktop WPF application (.Net Framework 4.5) and one of tasks is to save multiple files to zip archive. I made 2 methods. First to create zip, second to read from it.

```
    public static String GetFileContent(String zipPath, String entityName)
    {
        String retVal = String.Empty;

        using (ZipArchive zipfile = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
        {                    
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipfile.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.Name.ToLower() == entityName)
                {
                    using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
                    {
                        retVal = s.ReadToEnd();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public static void SetArchive(String path, String zipName, Dictionary<String, String> files)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, zipName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {                    
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> file in files)
                {
                    var entry = zip.CreateEntry(file.Key, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                    using (Stream s = entry.Open())
                    {           
                        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Value);
                        s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                }                    
            }            
        }
    }
```

Thing is that zip archive created and far manager and WinRAR can open it, but when I use second method to read its content I keep getting

> Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.
>      at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadCentralDirectory()
>      at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.get_Entries()
>      at Microsoft.MCS.SPPal.Storage.StorageObject.GetFileContent(String zipPath, String entityName) in z:\Home Inc\Microsoft.MCS.SPPal\Microsoft.MCS.SPPal\Storage\StorageObject.cs:line 32
>      at Microsoft.MCS.SPPal.MainWindow..ctor() in z:\Home Inc\Microsoft.MCS.SPPal\Microsoft.MCS.SPPal\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 48

As a part of experiment i created new archive in far manager and opened it up with GetFileContent method, and it works like a charm. So i think error should be in SetArchive method.

Any help would be awesome, it's 3 a.m. and i'm quite stuck.

P.S: I know code design suck, it was rewritten dozens of times.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> For better compression you can use 7zip library. In this way:

```
public void AddToArchive(string fileToBeZipped, string zipDestination)
{
    DirectoryInfo Di = new DirectoryInfo(zipDestination);
    StringBuilder sb_archiveFile = new StringBuilder(zipDestination + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Di.Name + @".7z");
    string archiveFile = sb_archiveFile.ToString();


    SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();

    Console.WriteLine("zip destination : " + Di.Name);
    if (!File.Exists(fileToBeZipped))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Appending {0} to Archive ", fileToBeZipped);
        compressor.CompressionMode = SevenZip.CompressionMode.Append;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating {0} at Destination {1}....", fileToBeZipped, archiveFile);
        Console.WriteLine("CREATING:: ");
        compressor.CompressionMode = SevenZip.CompressionMode.Create;
    }
    compressor.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Normal;
    compressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma;
    compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Append;

    compressor.CompressDirectory(zipDestination, archiveFile);



    compressor.CompressStream(streamer, streamer2);
}
```

And call a method with: AddToArchive(inFolder, splitIntoDir);

You can download a source code of 7zip [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip/7zIntf15.zip).

You can install a Nuget package for 7zip [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipSharp/) for Visual Studio.

Comment: The question was how to create a new ZipArchive correctly.  ZipArchive != SevenZipCompressor.

Comment: This didn't help answer the question stated in the title.

Comment: This was one of my first posts, my only intention was to help with other solution, but sorry if my solution is not liked by anyone.

Comment: @Joseph it's not about whether your solution is good in its own right or not, it's just unexpected to find an answer about 7zip to a question about ZipArchive.

Comment: I agree in large part with the other people, and he definitely should have removed the words "For better compression you can use 7zip library." However, I VERY much appreciate learning there was even this other library available to do the same task, a task that directly applies to the core function being asked about. I think this should not be marked as the answer though. I wish SO had perhaps an "auxilliary answer or response" tag.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work by adding an explicit call to Dispose() on the ZipArchive before it went out of scope in the SetArchive() method.

```
zip.Dispose();
```

Comment: You mean `using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(...))` didn't do its job? `using` blocks are specifically meant to be used with disposable objects...

Comment: Good point.  I wasn't using "using".  Switching to "using" works fine also.

Comment: OP's code has `using` blocks for all disposables, feel free to edit your post and add your full working code :)

Answer (score 1):

When trying to open zip files containing files that were greater than 4 GB before compression that had been compressed using Deflate64 (created via Windows shell or 7-zip) I got

```
Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory
```

when decompressing with `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` on Windows 2012 R2. These files seemed to be legitimate zips because Windows Shell, 7-zip and Info-zip could decompress them. The only large file zip archives that decompressed without error with `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` were those created with Info-zip's Zip64.

Comment: I was trying to fix another error - `"The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method"`, and your answer worked for that! After compressing the zip with Info-zip in WSL it unzipped like charm with `System.IO.Compression`!